# Which backend does Cairo use on Ubuntu?

Tags: graphics, opengl, cairo

Does Cairo on Ubuntu use the X11 or the OpenGL backend?

And if someone knows: Does the OpenGL backend render everything on the CPU and then just display it using OpenGL or does it use the shaders to do the rendering? And which OpenGL version/extensions does it require? Is it much faster?

Comment: To get more answers please try to ask questions on a single topic only. You may consider to ask the OpenGL part in a second question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Cairo](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/libcairo2) 2D vector graphics library uses X11 and the X renderer as backend. There are no dependencies on OpenGL.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like they switched to the OpenGL backend for Ubuntu 11.10.

Edit: And back again before the release.